# Inserting multiple values against multiple column names in mysql using Python3 and pymysql

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm looking for a clean way to add multiple values on one row which corresponds to a list of columns in mysql.

Essentially I have two lists:

```
cols = ['Col_A', 'Col_B','Col_E', 'Col_H, 'Col_n'....]
vals = ['1','56','HEX 00 A0 DB 00', 'Pass', '87'....]
```

The lists lengths can be 100+ items.  Both cols and vals lists will be the same length, so each cols item has a corresponding vals item.

I am using pymysql to connect to an SQL database on a network storage device running MariaDB.

Here's a snippet of my non-working function attempt at passing the two lists:

```
def add_to_database(cols, vals):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='11.22.33.44',
                             user='usr',
                             password='pass',
                             db='my_db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             autocommit=True)

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE data_tbl (%s)" % 'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY')
    except:
        pass

    # Add Column and Values lists to database here

    for item in cols:
        try:
            # First add columns if not already present
            cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE data_tbl ADD COLUMN " + str(item))
        except:
            # Pass column add if already present
            pass

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO data_tbl '{0}' VALUES '{1}';".format(cols, vals,))

    conn.close()

    return
```

I'm still new to SQL and I've also been playing around with the SQL syntax, so apologies if the code looks a bit odd now.

The common error I get is below:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''('Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_E', 'Col_H', 'Col_...' at line 1")
```

Comment: I don't know Python, but I think your problem is the `'`'s around the `{0}` and `{1}`.

Comment: Thanks CptMisery, I gave it a try but no luck, might be a Python issue.  Having said that, is it common to post a large number of values to columns at once in SQL?

Comment: I found the solution >>>   sql = "INSERT INTO data_tbl ({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(', '.join(cols), ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));

Comment: Not sure how common it is, but I've done it a few times